# Value from MVC Controller Method function not displaying in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My View isn't rendering the Tax variable that is being returned via a method in my controller. The method in my controller returns Tax. The method appears like this:

```
public string GetTax(decimal feednumber, string cityname, string actualproduct)
    {
        var myresult = "";
        var tax = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select tax from OPISPricing where FeedNumber=@fn and CityName=@cn and ActualProduct=@ap", new SqlParameter("@fn", feednumber), new SqlParameter("@cn", cityname), new SqlParameter("@ap", actualproduct));
        foreach (var thing in tax)
        {
           myresult = thing;    
        }

        return myresult;
    }
```

In my View I'm trying to display the result like this:

```
     @{
     var Tax = ((OPISLocationsController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetTax(item.FeedNumber, item.CityName, thing);
     Html.DisplayName(Tax);
     }
```

The reason for the apparent redundancy of Var Tax= and Html.DisplayName(Tax) was so that I could place a breakpoint and verify that the value is actually being returned and it IS. So why isn't it showing up when the page is rendered?

Comment: Why do you have logic in a view.  That method should be in the controller populating a *ViewModel* (a model that should represent all the data the view needs).  Secondly, `DisplayName()` won't display the value in the variable `tax`, I'd be surprised if it every displayed a value at all.

Comment: I'm moving an application from ASP Classic to MVC using as close to a 1 to 1 relationship as possible. Writing logic into the View is bad practice but in this case it's what is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is on the 'Html.DisplayName()' it has to be outside the '@{}', try something like this:

```
 @{
 var Tax = ((OPISLocationsController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetTax(item.FeedNumber, item.CityName, thing);

 }  @Html.DisplayName(Tax);
```

Comment: It does not *have to be* out side of `@{}`.  While that does work, it can work inside as long as [it is escaped properly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AM6jpU) by `@:`.  And your code will add an extra semicolon, because HtmlHelper methods executed outside of a code block do not need a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks @ErikPhilips I had forgotten about the escape sequence.